# TFS Plug-in for Eclipse (TEE) Timeout on Checkin of Multiple Items

Tags: linux, eclipse, tfs, eclipse-plugin

I've been using Eclipse with the TFS Plug-in for the last few months. Even though the plug-in performance has alwalys been an issue, with many seconds delay to do simple tasks, it always completed the commands (check-in, check-out, add item...).

Since yesterday a new issue appeared that I cannot solve. Whenever I try to checkin multiple files the plugin shows the progress bar for the first file but it never moves. After a couple of minutes it times out.

What I find very odd is that I can check-in filed individually (one by one) with no problems. Also I can check-out and add items as usual.

Using the same machine everything works fine from Visual Studio (check-in, check-out, add item...).

Does anyone have an idea of what is wrong?

Thanks for the support,

Bernardo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much testing I couldn't figure out the problem.

I took the opportunity to upgrade the Eclipse CDT to Mars release and apparently it worked, so now I can checkin multiple items again.